# New 5TB drive causes others to fail until removed

Tags: hard-drive

I just got a brand new 5TB drive that came with an enclosure. The idea was to move my games drive to the new drive where the old drive was 2TB and was failing due to bad sectors. So I took the 5TB drive out of the enclosure, and put it where the 2TB drive use to be to get it prepped. Considering the ports are SATA (6GB/s) and hot-swappable, computer was will on.

The computer did not see the TB drive. So I plugged it into a USB3.0 (SATA now empty) to SATA dock. Still didn't see it. Plugged it back into the USB3.0 enclosure and it saw it... good I know its working and SMART says everything good. Hard Disk Sentinel marked it as PERFECT.

I put the 5TB drive back into the SATA port. Nothing. I tried another power connector. Nothing. I took the SATA cable from the drive just below it plugged it in. Nothing. I then took the original SATA and plugged it into the drive I stole its SATA cable from, it works! But, the drive I took it from is not currently connected at this point, being 1TB.

I figured something is limiting the amount of TB's I can utilize but doesn't Windows 10 support something like 16 Exabyte's?

I then disconnected various other drives, trying to figure out a limit, couldn't find it. Sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't. So I figured it was an issue with the Asus Z170 SATA controller (all drivers are up to date, so is the EUFI). At this point put the 5TB back in the USB3.0 enclosure figuring I'd bypass the SATA controller. The 3TB drive that is used for storage is now crapping out as if Windows isn't sure how to handle the drives?

I'm at a loss as to why I can't use this 5TB drive in combination with my other drives.

Currently system has the following:

- 3TB GPT Storage NTFS
- 512 MBR Windows NTFS SSD
- 256 MBR Empty NTFS SSD
- 1TB MBR Virtual Machines NTFS
- 640GB MBR 2 Partitions Download & Bitcoin Blockchain NTFS
- 3TB GPT Media NTFS RAID0
- 8TB GPT Backup NTFS
- 2TB GPT Games NTFS (BAD DRIVE)

I also have a DVD burner and a Blu-ray burner. At one point the 5TB drive was recognized after removing the DVD burner and the Virtual Machines drive.

Can anyone explain to me why I cannot swap the 2TB games drive with a brand new 5TB drive?

Running Windows 10 x64 Enterprise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem! As this was specific to a motherboard issue and SATA/M.2 ports. In the event logs I kept seeing disk errors for read/write access along with The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur.

Eventually this had gone away when I set my windows drive (Samsung 960 pro) to M.2 but then the board kept switching it back randomly to sata express thus kicking out the other sata ports (which weren't even on the express lane, and ended up kicking out the USB3.0 drives). Weird!

So enough was enough, removed the M.2 card, put in a PCI extension card and put the M.2 there, bios now holds onto the M.2 settings and all drives have enough room to breathe through the sata controller on the chipset.

Again, this is specific to my issue but if you come across drives not being recognized or randomly disappearing, check the information on your motherboard for SATA controllers and limitations. And don't trust the EUFI! I miss the days of the bios... plain old bios... RIP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drives in a desktop/workstation w/o a hardware scsi controller as most have software controllers things with get stupid over 2Tb. The problem with the larger drives are generally only 5400 speed drive and as generally used for NAS storage. The seek time on a 5TB drive even using a 7k speed drive is crazy. They big drive also do not come with a Buffer large enough to handle any large queries or any delay by other drives. Sata controllers as generally software and again you run into timing issues when the drive are to diverse in size. The "Best Practice" is to use no more than a 2TB drive and if you are using Linux as your base OS or VMware is to NOT RAID the drives even of its just a RAID 0/1. On my VMware server where I have 3 500G drive 7200 rpm and one 3GB for mostly .IOS CD/DVD files is actually run the OS off of a 128Meg USB3 drive where I loaded the VMware OS. One my Desktop I use a 128GB SSD for the OS and all the other drives (total of 9TB) are storage or I use the D:/ drive as my Program file files as well. One this to remember is if you have a lot of RAM such as 32GB, you need to have your paging file in windows at least twice that size and DO NOT put it on the C:/ drive as you can run into disk contention issues. Place it on any other or multiple dives for your Windows 10/2008/2012 system. Linux system obviously use a SWAP file area for paging memory overflow. The SWAP file should be place on a drive other that /root.  As always these comments are IMHO. Cheers and good luck